# Разрешить только разрешенное Запрет "перезаписи" $_GET параметров, sef-url, чпу

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

Есть такие чпу (или чпу такого вида)

http://oop/activity/posts-pg1-sort2/

Если к этому чпу добавить ?pg=3

получится http://oop/activity/posts-pg1-sort2/?pg=3

Всё работает, всё хорошо, но сам чпу указывает на стр №1.

**Как сделать так, чтобы параметры не перезаписывались таким способом?** Уверен это можно решить при помощи .htaccess (или как?)?

**ДОПИСЫВАЮ**
Пока гулял на свежем воздухе, ко мне пришла идея:
средствами php удалять всё что после **?** и делать редирект. Если завтра код напишется - придется самому писать ответ на свой вопрос.

но всё-таки интересно можно ли это сделать при помощи .htaccess ?

**ДОписываю еще:**

```
RewriteRule ^activity/posts-pg([0-9]+)-sort(1|2)/$ show.php?wsh=27&pg=$1&sort=$2 [QSA,L]
```

*Но это не поможет ни вам ни мне (?)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

@teran , наверное вы недопоняли меня. У меня ВСЕ чпу (ссылки) хорошие и правильные.
Тут речь о том что **если кто-то из пользователей  руками сам добавит в адресную строку** `?pg=3`, то получится "глюк" как на скриншоте.

Можно ли такое поведение считать как глюк, баг, страшную ошибку... - я не знаю.

Comment: вы считаете нормальны задать вопрос про rewriteRule и не привести ваши правила в коде? `QSA` добавить, возможно, поможет. будет два параметра, и мб  в _get попадет последний. Но вообще по сути это ерунда какая-то. В чем необходимость перекрывать параметр повторяя его? почему нельзя сделать просто ссылку `posts-pg3-sort2` ?

Comment: @teran У меня ВСЕ чпу (ссылки) хорошие и правильные. Тут речь о том что если кто-то из пользователей руками сам добавит в адресную строку ?pg=3, то получится "глюк" как на скриншоте.

Можно ли такое поведение считать как глюк, баг, страшную ошибку... - я не знаю.

Comment: так уберите `QSA` если он не нужен вам

Comment: @teran вау, да это помогло, но добавило проблем при проверке кук. Но можно сказать уже всё решено. Если бы я знал что значит `QSL` этой проблемы не было бы. Благодарствую!, Но всё равно подумаю еще и над своим решением на php.

Comment: ерундой занимаетесь, никто не будет сидеть и подбирать имена параметров, чтобы получить такой нелепый баг. Хотите исключить возможность подбора, просто переименуйте `pg` в какой нибудь `__qmnahfu3jsd9` и все дела.